# AndroidStudio. Непойму как отлаживать приложение после обновления 2.1

Tags: android, android-studio, отладка

Раньше все было хорошо я запускал приложение на устройстве и смотрел LogCat. Сейчас вышло новомодное обновление что перезагружается только текущее Activity, я нажимаю первый раз зеленый треугольник он запускает приложение все нормально, после я вношу изменения запускаю Run второй раз но никаких изменений на устройстве не вносится, я нажимаю красный квадрат и запускаю снова и это не помогает, приходится переподключать устройство, как этим пользоваться, как вернуть старую отладку?

Comment: Час назад был такой же вопрос. Вам надо или убрать функцию "Instant run` в настройках студии, или запускать принудительно новую версию приложения по нажатию `Ctrl+F5` или откатиться на версию студии 1.5. Подробности по ссылке на вопрос-дубликат.

Answer (score 1):

Изменить настройки Instant Run можно в

**Settings or Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run**

Comment: Спасибо, предпочел перезапускать кнопкой с серым квадратиком и круглой зеленой стрелкой.